# how to retrive json object using retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I'am trying to retrieve this in my class but i got an error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
my response from web service is {"last_question":"0","level":"0","error":"0"}
thank you

Json

```
    {"last_question":"0","level":"0","error":"0"}
```

Activtiy

```
    //calling from MainActivity
        private void get()
            {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setLenient()
                        .create();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .build();

                API mApi = retrofit.create(API.class);

                Call<Example> call = mApi.getdata();
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response)
                    {
                        System.out.println(response.body().getError());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t)
                    {

                        System.out.println(t.getMessage());
                    }
                });


            }
```

//pojo class

```
public class Example {
    private String last_question;
    private String level;
    private String error;
//all getter andd setter are is here
}
```

Comment: **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING** Check your response. seems to be string while your code expects a `JSONObject`. Your code looks alright

Comment: i hosted the same json here https://api.myjson.com/bins/cw29l to test and the same android code works except its a get request and a header content-type to accept application/json

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Your server doesn't respond with your desired response. In fact its HTML-Code which is returned:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("9cc75ba79032859c712d6ecb862cfde7");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://advancedcalc.byethost8.com/test.php?i=2";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Old (wrong) answer:

You forgot to add `@SerializedName(name)` Annotations to your fields within the Example  class:

```
@SerializedName("last_question")
private String last_question;

@SerializedName("level")
private String level;

@SerializedName("error")
private String error;
```

Comment: you don't need to use annotations when names are identical, it's only when you have to use different names

Comment: @Nikul you need to check the response from server. Seems you end up getting a string while your code expects jsonobject. Your android code seems fine

Comment: I updated my answer. Seems your server responds with HTML code.

Comment: @Nikul check your headers. Do you have Headers application/json?? Check your server log

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.nik.myapplication.Example.getLast_question()' on a null object reference  after running on local host got this error @Raghunandan

Comment: @Nikul Use a debugger to find out whats null and fix it. Your android code is fine accept that you need a header content-type:application/json